# SVG triangle - why is it so small?

Tags: svg, geometry, polygon

I have created two simple SVG files for play and pause icons:

Play:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="5" height="5">
    <polygon points="0,0 0,4 4,2" style="fill: red;" />
</svg>
```

Pause:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="5" height="5">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="2" height="5" style="fill: red;" />
    <rect x="3" y="0" width="2" height="5" style="fill: red;" />
</svg>
```

They are both simple, 5x5 icons. The pause icon is being generated just as I'd assume, but I have a problem with play icon. For some reason, after scaling it's smaller than pause icon. I thought I calculated triangle's coords properly, one of the points is (4, 2), which makes the right middle of 5,5 image. But the result looks like this:

[image: Play & Pause]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, triangle has the height of 4, rectangles have height of 5, and that's what you can see here :)

try:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="5" height="5">
<polygon points="0,0 0,5 5,2.5" style="fill: red;" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but I don't understand why :)

Comment: Ok, I know next to nothing about SVG, but: (0,0-0,1)(0,1-0,2)(0,2-0,3)(0,3-0,4) - if you divide your 5-height shape into 1-size segments, you can see, that (0,4) is not really 5-segments from the top :)

Comment: I don't know why you think that in 5x5 the coords go from (0,0) to (4,4). That WOULD be true for 5-size (or 5x5) arrays in many programming languages: `var x = new string[5]; x[5] <-error! x[4] <- ok`, but in euclidean geometry you use in drawing stuff the range is from (0,0) to (width, height), inclusive :)

Comment: You are right, I probably confused it with raster graphics. I need to think that there are indefinitely small "blocks" in vector graphics. I will accept your answer, there's just one small tweak to do: it's (5, 2.5) instead of (4, 2.5).

Comment: Exactly. This is basically like high-school geometry :)

Comment: Yes it should fill the whole area. However I made it a little different, I came up doing 1000x866 shape, because that makes almost perfect equilateral triangle.